# EF 4.1 code-first: How to select an entity with it's collection-property's count

Tags: lambda, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, code-first, navigation-properties

I have an entity named *`Tag`* with a navigation property (collection) named *`Articles`*. The *`Tag`* has a ignored-property named *`ArticleCount`* that used to save tha associated *`Article`* s count (just in run-time and to use in views- ignored against the DB). See:

```
public class Tag{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Article> Articles { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public int ArticleCount { get; set; }

}
```

How can I select all *`Tag`* s (or one) with it's *`ArticleCount`* in **ONE** query against the dataBase -in **entity framework 4.1 code-first, with lambda expressions** please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var tagsAndCounts =  from tag in context.Tags
                     where ...
                     select new { tag, count = tag.Articles.Count() }
var tagsWithCount = tagsAndCounts.ToList()
                                 .Select(x => 
                                         {
                                             x.tag.ArticleCount = x.count;
                                             return x.tag;
                                         };
```

(I would design this differently - `ArticleCount` should not be part of the model, or it should be a projection on `Articles`, which you could eager-load using `Include()`. But this does what you want)

---

Update: my design.

```
public class Tag
{
   ...
   public int ArticleCount { get { return Articles.Count; } }
}

var tagsWithEagerLoadedArticles = context.Tags.Include(x => x.Articles)
                                         .Where(...).Etc();
```

Of course, whether this performs well or not depends on the the expected article count per tag. If it's a few dozen, this will work reasonably, while being cleaner than the other approach. If it's hundreds, the other one is better.

Now, if that's the case, you should use an anonymous or named presentation type instead of reusing the entity.

Comment: That's more nicely written than my solution!

Comment: Can you left an example of your suggestion please? Thanks a lot.

Comment: In my case using anonymous is better; I used that design (the second) before; also, I used the `ArticleCount` as a just `getter` property and read it from cache, but I was looking for a better way. Now I think the first code-snippet you provide to me, is better that all others. Special thanks. I accept your A. And another Q, can I mail you a question please? If you have time? I'm sorry to left this here, but in your profile isn't any mail-address and SOF doesn't provide any relationship or connection for users. My mail: kavand.ds[at]gmail I'll be so thanks if you allow me. With best regards.

Comment: If it's a technical question, please post another question here.

Answer (score 1):

Example for *all* tags:

```
var result = context.Tags
    .Select(t => new
    {
        Tag = t,
        ArticleCount = t.Articles.Count()
    });

foreach (var a in result)
    a.Tag.ArticleCount = a.ArticleCount;

var tags = result.Select(a => a.Tag).ToList();
```

This is only one query and the copy happens in memory. I believe that there is no other way than copying the `ArticleCount` from the anonymous result objects into the tags because you cannot project directly into an entity, so you can't use `Select(t => new Tag { ... });`. You could use another *named* type instead of the anonymous type but not an entity type.